# How is nginx able to serve a site in a directory which belongs to root, as well as all of its files?

Tags: linux, nginx

A part of my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
    #user nobody;
    user http;

    worker_processes  1;

    events {
        worker_connections 1024;
    }

    #.......
```

One of my websites:

```
ls -al /var/web/site123.com/index.html 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 761 Jul  3 07:31 /var/web/site123.com/index.html


ls -ald /var/web/site123.com
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  3 07:31 /var/web/site123.com
```

Given that the directory of the website and `index.html` too belong to `root`, how's nginx able to work and serve the website at all? nginx worker is run under `http` user and website is accessible via internet.

```
root      873848  0.0  0.0  22392  1436 ?        Ss   07:27   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid; error_log stderr;
http      873849  0.0  0.2  22396  4264 ?        S    07:27   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

How's that that `http` user has an access to the path that only `root` is supposed to be permitted to access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check your directory permission.

As you can see from the output of the ls command

```bash
ls -al /var/web/site123.com/index.html 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 761 Jul  3 07:31 /var/web/site123.com/index.html


ls -ald /var/web/site123.com
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul  3 07:31 /var/web/site123.com
```

Everyone can access to your directory because you gave the  read /execution permission 755  to everyone and for the index.html you gave the read permission to everyone.